# How do I modify data of a column in one table when I update data of column in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables 'login' and 'editprofile' with the same column 'password'. Whenever a user edits his/her password which is under 'editprofile', it should also change the column 'password' of 'login' table. Is there a way to execute this, without joining both tables? Thanks.

Comment: This could be done by setting a trigger on the column. However, I would strongly suggest that you revisit your database schema and normalize the data in such a way that a password would only be stored once. Maybe a `USER` table with a `UserID` column as a foreign key reference to `login` and `editprofile`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of database are you working with?  Set up a trigger on one table and have it enter the info on the other table...  Something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Update_profile_password` AFTER UPDATE ON `login`
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE `Database`.`ProfileTable`
SET password = NEW.passwd
```

should start you off nicely

Comment: @Josh Triggers work on MySQL -> http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/introduction-to-mysql-triggers--net-12226.

Comment: is it by chance phpmyadmin?  because they have a wizzard that writes most of the code for you.

Comment: yeah. But I can't find it.

Comment: I just made stuff up quickly